# How to import class in Python from inside git repo

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, python-import

I am having problems importing a class from a Python package.

I am trying to import the Python class into a Python script. At the top of the Python script I have:

```
from myutility.utilities import PostgresInteract
```

The error I get is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myutility.utilities'
```

The myutility package has deployed locally from a git branch (hosted on bitbucket and installed successfully using `python3 -m pip install git+[url of the myutility repo]@[branch name]`).

The directory structure under the `myutility` repo is as follows:

```
myutility
    - utilities
        databases.py (this file contains the PostgresInteract class)
```

I appreciate I may need to import the exact file that contains the `PostgresInteract` class using `from myutility.utilities.databases import PostgresInteract` but this doesn't work either (I still get the same error as above).

The `setup.py` has the following entries (I wonder if I am exposing the packages correctly in the repo):

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='myutility',
      version='1.0',
      packages=['myutility','myutility.utilities']
```

I have `__init__.py` files in each of the package directories already.

Please could someone help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick note: in `setup.py`, you should not include `'myutility.utilities'` in the `packages=` argument. `setup.py` handles children of packages, or takes a `scripts=` parameter to identify individual python files.

Anyway, to resolve this error, best to review the directory structure. The directory structure that `setup.py` expects is:

```
my_project
  myutility
    utilities.py
  more_stuff
    things.py
  setup.py
```

Note that `setup.py` is in the folder called `my_project`. `setup.py` is therefore converting `my_project` into a package. Once the `my_project` package is installed, python doesn't use the namespace `my_project`. Instead, every subdirectory in `my_project` that is included in the `packages` field of the `setup.py` script gets added to the namespace for imports. So in the `setup.py` file, it looks like

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='my_project',
      version='1.0',
      packages=['myutility']
```

And the install command becomes `pip3 install -e my_project`. Once this is done, then python has access to the `myutility` namespace. Python knows nothing about any directory called `my_project`. And it knows everything about the contents of the `myutility` directory.

Comment: Thank you. This pointed me in the right direction. I did also need to change the following line in the `setup-py` file: `packages=find_packages()`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from myutility.utilities.database import PostgresInteract
```

Comment: I've tried this already but get the same `ModuleNotFoundError`