# Relative imports causing error when running the tool through an internal script

Tags: python, module, package, python-import

I'm stuck on how to manage the imports in the tool I'm working on. The problem is, I need to be able to launch my tool GUI through the launcher.py file, but also be able to call manager.py from another project to access some of its functions. I tried to use relative imports, but it's causing me issues when running the internal launcher.

Here's a simplified version of my project:

```
tool_name
  launcher.py
  core
    manager.py
  ui
    window.py
  utils
    operators.py
```

launcher.py

```
from ui.window import Window
gui = Window()
```

window.py

```
from ..core.manager import Manager

class Window():
    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = Manager()
```

manager.py

```
from ..utils import operators

class Manager():
    # ...
    def addition(self, a, b):
        return operators.sum(a+b)
```

When calling the Manager class from another tool through this code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path/to/tool/parent/folder")
from tool_name.core.manager import Manager
Manager()
```

... it works, but when running launcher.py, I get the error : `attempted relative import beyond top-level package` on the `from ..core.manager import Manager` in window.py

What would be the cleanest way to correct this ?

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports are the bane of a Python dev's existence. I feel your pain my friend. So this bit of code: `from ..core.manager import Manager`, the `..` searches one level up *from whichever directory the python script is being run from*. It does NOT search one level up relative to `/tool_name/ui/window`.

So move everything over to absolute imports. In `window.py` change the import to `from core.manager import Manager`. Now for this to be available and not give errors, it has to be that `core` directory is on the python path. If you're running locally, easy peasy. If you're using some external tool, then *that* tool will have its own directory structure, and this may not work. That's where you go the route of using `setup.py` files to convert the `tool_name` directory into a python package, and importing the package into the external tool.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! But adding the core directory directly into the `sys.path` might cause issues, as I have other tools that also have a core folder and that will be called in the same project. If I do a sys.path.append of both tools, then try to call their managers by `from core.manager import Manager`, how will it know which tool I'm talking about? That's the main reason I wanted to use the `from tool_name.core.manager import Manager` instead, in the secondary tool

Comment: Pretty sure that's a more fundamental namespace limit then. So your problem is less so "in this `tool_name` package my relative imports are failing", and more "I have a bunch of things with the same name and was previously getting away with it because of relative imports". I can't speak for your other directories that have `core`, but when you package your `tool_name` directory via `setup.py`, you can opt to give it a name e.g. `my_package` so that `import my_package.core` becomes available. If you package those other dependencies like this, you can control the namespace to prevent conflicts

Comment: Alright, thanks, I haven't had to use setup.py yet, but I'll take a look at how it works, and see if it helps me solve my issue :-)

Comment: Best of luck. Here's an answer to a question I did from several months ago that gives a sample `setup.py` and sample directory structure. :-)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75817887/how-to-import-class-in-python-from-inside-git-repo/75818071#75818071